# How to Move Opencart From Root to Subfolder

Tags: opencart

I have a novice question that you can help me easily. I have installed OC in root. I want to move it to a subfolder in the root. For example,if I have www.mysite.com, I want to move it in www.mysite.com/Subfolder. I have redirected www.mysite.com to www.mysite.com/Subfolder through htaccess in the root. What changes I need to make to config.php and admin/config.php and to htaccess in the Subfolder. Would I need to make changes to other files too in the Subfolder? How to deal with databases in www.mysite.com? Where I need to export it? How can I achieve this? I am using OC 3.0.2.0. I would be thankful for any help. **My Subfolder config.php looks like this**

```
define('HTTP_SERVER', 'http://www.example.com/');

// HTTPS
define('HTTPS_SERVER', 'http://www.example.com/');

// DIR
define('DIR_APPLICATION', '/home/user/public_html/catalog/');
define('DIR_SYSTEM', '/home/user/public_html/system/');
define('DIR_IMAGE', '/home/user/public_html/image/');
define('DIR_STORAGE', '/home/user/storedata1/storage/');
define('DIR_LANGUAGE', DIR_APPLICATION . 'language/');
define('DIR_TEMPLATE', DIR_APPLICATION . 'view/theme/');
define('DIR_CONFIG', DIR_SYSTEM . 'config/');
define('DIR_CACHE', DIR_STORAGE . 'cache/');
define('DIR_DOWNLOAD', DIR_STORAGE . 'download/');
define('DIR_LOGS', DIR_STORAGE . 'logs/');
define('DIR_MODIFICATION', DIR_STORAGE . 'modification/');
define('DIR_SESSION', DIR_STORAGE . 'session/');
define('DIR_UPLOAD', DIR_STORAGE . 'upload/');
```

**and my Subfolder admin config.php looks like this**

```
// HTTP
define('HTTP_SERVER', 'http://www.example.com/admin/');
define('HTTP_CATALOG', 'http://www.example.com/');

// HTTPS
define('HTTPS_SERVER', 'http://www.example.com/admin/');
define('HTTPS_CATALOG', 'http://www.example.com/');

// DIR
define('DIR_APPLICATION', '/home/user/public_html/admin/');
define('DIR_SYSTEM', '/home/user/public_html/system/');
define('DIR_IMAGE', '/home/user/public_html/image/');
define('DIR_STORAGE', '/home/user/storedata1/storage/');
define('DIR_CATALOG', '/home/user/public_html/catalog/');
define('DIR_LANGUAGE', DIR_APPLICATION . 'language/');
define('DIR_TEMPLATE', DIR_APPLICATION . 'view/template/');
define('DIR_CONFIG', DIR_SYSTEM . 'config/');
define('DIR_CACHE', DIR_STORAGE . 'cache/');
define('DIR_DOWNLOAD', DIR_STORAGE . 'download/');
define('DIR_LOGS', DIR_STORAGE . 'logs/');
define('DIR_MODIFICATION', DIR_STORAGE . 'modification/');
define('DIR_SESSION', DIR_STORAGE . 'session/');
define('DIR_UPLOAD', DIR_STORAGE . 'upload/');
```

**Please advise me how to edit my Subfolder config.php and Subfolder/admin/config.php and in which places I need to put my Subfolder**

Comment: For that you must modify only `config.php`, `admin/config.php` and `.htaccess`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three places you'll need to make the edits:

1. OpenCartSiteFolder/config.php
2. OpenCartSiteFolder/admin/config.php
3. Update .htaccess file

Step 1. You must modify the paths in the config.php to match the name of the new folder you're placing the site into (assuming you're hosting on linux shared hosting):

```
// HTTP
define('HTTP_SERVER', 'http://www.website.com/subfolder_name/');

// HTTPS
define('HTTPS_SERVER', 'https://www.website.com/subfolder_name/');

// DIR
define('DIR_APPLICATION', '/usr/www/users/ftp_username/subfolder_name/catalog/');
define('DIR_SYSTEM', '/usr/www/users/ftp_username/subfolder_name/system/');
define('DIR_IMAGE', '/usr/www/users/ftp_username/subfolder_name/image/');
define('DIR_LANGUAGE', '/usr/www/users/ftp_username/subfolder_name/catalog/language/');
define('DIR_TEMPLATE', '/usr/www/users/ftp_username/subfolder_name/catalog/view/theme/');
define('DIR_CONFIG', '/usr/www/users/ftp_username/subfolder_name/system/config/');
define('DIR_CACHE', '/usr/www/users/ftp_username/subfolder_name/system/storage/cache/');
define('DIR_DOWNLOAD', '/usr/www/users/ftp_username/subfolder_name/system/storage/download/');
define('DIR_LOGS', '/usr/www/users/ftp_username/subfolder_name/system/storage/logs/');
define('DIR_MODIFICATION', '/usr/www/users/ftp_username/subfolder_name/system/storage/modification/');
define('DIR_UPLOAD', '/usr/www/users/ftp_username/subfolder_name/system/storage/upload/');
```

Step 2: You must modify the paths in the website/sub_folder/admin/config.php to match the name of the new folder you're placing the site into:

```
// HTTP
define('HTTP_SERVER', 'http://www.website.com/subfolder_name/');

// HTTPS
define('HTTPS_SERVER', 'https://www.website.com/subfolder_name/');

// HTTP
define('HTTP_SERVER', 'http://www.website.com/subfolder_name/admin/');
define('HTTP_CATALOG', 'http://www.website.com/subfolder_name/');

// HTTPS
define('HTTPS_SERVER', 'https://www.website.com/subfolder_name/admin/');
define('HTTPS_CATALOG', 'https://www.website.com/subfolder_name/');

// DIR
define('DIR_APPLICATION', '/usr/www/users/ftp_username/subfolder_name/admin/');
define('DIR_SYSTEM', '/usr/www/users/ftp_username/subfolder_name/system/');
define('DIR_IMAGE', '/usr/www/users/ftp_username/subfolder_name/image/');
define('DIR_LANGUAGE', '/usr/www/users/ftp_username/subfolder_name/admin/language/');
define('DIR_TEMPLATE', '/usr/www/users/ftp_username/subfolder_name/admin/view/template/');
define('DIR_CONFIG', '/usr/www/users/ftp_username/subfolder_name/system/config/');
define('DIR_CACHE', '/usr/www/users/ftp_username/subfolder_name/system/storage/cache/');
define('DIR_DOWNLOAD', '/usr/www/users/ftp_username/subfolder_name/system/storage/download/');
define('DIR_LOGS', '/usr/www/users/ftp_username/subfolder_name/system/storage/logs/');
define('DIR_MODIFICATION', '/usr/www/users/ftp_username/subfolder_name/system/storage/modification/');
define('DIR_UPLOAD', '/usr/www/users/ftp_username/subfolder_name/system/storage/upload/');
define('DIR_CATALOG', '/usr/www/users/ftp_username/subfolder_name/catalog/');
```

You may also need to update your htaccess file as K.B. mentioned:
RewriteBase /subfolder_name/

Comment: Thanks Daniel for your help. But my config files are different. I do not know how to add Subfolder in DIR where paths are not mentioned,for example DIR_LANGUAGE etc. Please read my edited question and help me with respect to my both config files. Do I do not need to do anything with data bases? Thanks

Comment: @ArslanKhan I think K.B. has done this, if his answer works for you, please accept it so that other users can be helped too!

Comment: @ArslanKhan you're welcome my friend, that's what the community is for!

Answer (score 0):

config.php

```
 define('HTTP_SERVER', 'http://www.example.com/subfolder_name/');

    // HTTPS
    define('HTTPS_SERVER', 'http://www.example.com/subfolder_name/');

    // DIR
    define('DIR_APPLICATION', '/home/user/public_html/subfolder_name/catalog/');
    define('DIR_SYSTEM', '/home/user/public_html/subfolder_name/system/');
    define('DIR_IMAGE', '/home/user/public_html/subfolder_name/image/');
    define('DIR_STORAGE', '/home/user/storedata1/storage/');
    define('DIR_LANGUAGE', DIR_APPLICATION . 'language/');
    define('DIR_TEMPLATE', DIR_APPLICATION . 'view/theme/');
    define('DIR_CONFIG', DIR_SYSTEM . 'config/');
    define('DIR_CACHE', DIR_STORAGE . 'cache/');
    define('DIR_DOWNLOAD', DIR_STORAGE . 'download/');
    define('DIR_LOGS', DIR_STORAGE . 'logs/');
    define('DIR_MODIFICATION', DIR_STORAGE . 'modification/');
    define('DIR_SESSION', DIR_STORAGE . 'session/');
    define('DIR_UPLOAD', DIR_STORAGE . 'upload/');
```

Subfolder admin config.php should be:

```
// HTTP
define('HTTP_SERVER', 'http://www.example.com/subfolder_name/admin/');
define('HTTP_CATALOG', 'http://www.example.com/subfolder_name/');

// HTTPS
define('HTTPS_SERVER', 'http://www.example.com/subfolder_name/admin/');
define('HTTPS_CATALOG', 'http://www.example.com/subfolder_name/');

// DIR
define('DIR_APPLICATION', '/home/user/public_html/subfolder_name/admin/');
define('DIR_SYSTEM', '/home/user/public_html/subfolder_name/system/');
define('DIR_IMAGE', '/home/user/public_html/subfolder_name/image/');
define('DIR_STORAGE', '/home/user/storedata1/storage/');
define('DIR_CATALOG', '/home/user/public_html/subfolder_name/catalog/');
define('DIR_LANGUAGE', DIR_APPLICATION . 'language/');
define('DIR_TEMPLATE', DIR_APPLICATION . 'view/template/');
define('DIR_CONFIG', DIR_SYSTEM . 'config/');
define('DIR_CACHE', DIR_STORAGE . 'cache/');
define('DIR_DOWNLOAD', DIR_STORAGE . 'download/');
define('DIR_LOGS', DIR_STORAGE . 'logs/');
define('DIR_MODIFICATION', DIR_STORAGE . 'modification/');
define('DIR_SESSION', DIR_STORAGE . 'session/');
define('DIR_UPLOAD', DIR_STORAGE . 'upload/');
```

Comment: I am greately thankful for your time and help to solve my problem.